Auto-generated reference number repeats more than twice
I have been trying to create an automated reference number that can be used to identify each user, but in some aspect, there is a repetition in the number.
From my code, the reference number is supposed to be unique, but there are multiple of the same reference number. How can I create a unique reference number that cannot be repeated?
For example, if a reference number like 539873321 exists in the database table, it should generate a new one. But whenever I go to the page, a new reference number is created and in some cases it repeats the same number and I will have like 3 of the same reference number 539873321.
Please I want to create an auto-generated reference number that cannot be repeated, how can I do that please?
Here is my code to generate number automatically without repeating the same number:
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!this.IsPostBack)
    {
        AutoGenerateNumber();
    }
}

This code generates 9-digit automatic reference number:
private string GetAutoNumber()
{
    string numbers = "1234567890";
    string characters = numbers;
    int length = 9;
    string id = string.Empty;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
        string character = string.Empty;

        do
        {
            int index = new Random().Next(0, characters.Length);
            character = characters.ToCharArray()[index].ToString();
        } while (id.IndexOf(character) != -1);

        id += character;
    }

    return id;
}

This code is where is search the database table to see if the reference number exists, then it should generate another reference number:
private void AutoGenerateNumber()
{
    try
    {
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection())
        {
            con.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConString"].ConnectionString;
            SqlDataReader dr;

            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                // Here I tried to check the table to see if the 
                // reference number number already exists. And if it exists,
                // then it should automatically create a new one                         
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT reference_no FROM IDTable WHERE reference_no = @reference_no";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Reference_no", ReferenceLabel.Text);
                cmd.Connection = con;

                con.Open();
                dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
            }

            if (dr.HasRows)
            {
            }
            else
            {
                List<string> result = new List<string>();

                if (Session["Numbers"] != null)
                {
                    result = (List<string>)Session["Numbers"];
                }

                string number = GetAutoNumber();

                if (!result.Contains(number))
                {
                    result.Add(number);
                    Session["Numbers"] = result;
                    ReferenceLabel.Text = number;                          
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
}


Since you are using a SQL Server database in the backend - why not let the database handle the generation of unique numbers? It has things like SEQUENCE db objects that are specifically designed to exactly this!

If you want numbers to look random, generate a sequence then hash the value (with salt?). If you want to be certain that numbers are unique, create a unique index.

@marc_s note, the generator seems to create 9 digit numbers with no repeated digits

@donald your generator could perhaps be improved by reducing the whole method to just string.Concat(_characters.OrderBy(_=>Random.Shared.Next()).Take(9)) where _characters is a class level string. Do not perform new Random() in loops; one day you may be working with a runtime that seeds from the clock

We see your check against IDTable but not how you update IDTable. If those two things aren't properly connected for example with a transaction that locks that table and gets checking and changing together you are open to a bunch of concurrency problems.

First of all GetAutoNumber has no guarantee to be unique, it generates pseudo random numbers and it certainly can repeat (but i guess you knew that already).
But you then you check if the number exists in database (though your code does not reflect that, but I guess value passed to query would be generated with GetAutoNumber.
So, imagine if your code is executed in parallel by multiple threads (let's say 2 for simplicity).
Both threads has generated the same pseudo random number from GetAutoNumber. Both, at the same time check for its existence, which passes (this number does not exist yet). Both threads proceed further, eventually persisting the numbers, leading to duplication.
You need to apply some locking mechanism, such as lock, SemaphoreSlim, or other :)
The easiest would be to put under lock entire section "check if number exists in DB and if not, save it".
UPDATE
Example with lock
private object _lock = new();

private void AutoGenerateNumber()
{
    try
    {
        lock(_lock)
        {
            // your code
        }
    }
    catch (SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }
}


Please how can I apply locking mechanism to this. Can you show with an example, I'm just learning how to do this?

Just make a unique index on the DB column and repeatedly save til it works

@Donald I have included example.

@MichałTurczyn a side note on your catch block. By throwing a new exception you've lost the original exception and its stack trace. Also throwing System.Exception from user code is generally considered bad practice.

@iakobski sure, but i just copied OPs code

Sidenote about the locking. The shown solution fits a single process system. Where everything is guaranteed  to go through that code in the same memory space. If you have any kind of multiprocessing this isn't enough and its needs different mechanics. Another reason to use the database build in features to get unique values. They are created to deal with such problems.

@iakobski Okay. You mentioned that "by throwing a new exception you've lost the original exception and its stack trace. Also throwing System.Exception from user code is generally considered bad practice". Please what is the good practice?

@Ralf  I don't think using DB built-in features will give me what I want. For example, if you are creating a web app that generates receipt and the reference number on the receipt will be unique. E.g 033652421 (9 digits). DB built-in feature has auto increment and will not auto-generate the unique reference number, what it will do is increase the reference number such as 000000000 000000001 000000002.......1000000 00000001

@Donald In this case, don't catch it here at all if all you're doing is re-throwing. If you want to do something else in addition, like log the message, then re-throw the original exception using the simple throw;. If you want to throw a custom exception so you can catch it elsewhere, add the original exception as the InnerException which is inherited from System.Exception.

@Donald re: your response to Ralf. An auto-incremented reference number will be guaranteed to be unique. Your version will be very difficult to guarantee that. What are your special requirements? Why should the number be random rather than sequential?

My point was only that "lock" does not add value here in certain setups. To get something that behaves like a "lock" that then must be close or in the database and not in far away code. You got a few options already to get unique stuff instead of rolling your own solution. Those solutions in nature don't need locking and guarantee uniqueness. If that does not help you because of requirements you didn't tell then add those to the question so it can be discussed/helped with at a different more proper spot.

Don't try to build this yourself. Just about all databases have some way to create auto-incrementing IDs. This essentially amounts to atomically incrementing a shared number. This is often the default option if you just want a unique number to use as a primary key.
The other common alternative is UUID / GUID, this is a 128 bit random number. The large size makes properly constructed GUIDs unique in practice.
There are advantages and disadvantages to each options. GUIDs can be constructed on the client, and are globaly unique, not just in your database. But are larger, and it's random nature may make the databases job slightly harder.
If you expose the number to the user you probably want it to be random to prevent guessing of reference numbers. So either a GUID, or use a random 64-bit number and add it to a table with a unique constraint, and just retry with a new number if adding fails due to the constraint.
